# Instagram Grap Api returns empty data for recent media GET request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to get all related media to my hashtag **#Corona** which is identified with **ig-hashtag-id: 17843934877037015** so i'm sending my GET Request: `GET graph.facebook.com/17843934877037015/recent_media?user_id=myUserID`
It's supposed to work like it's shown on the facebook documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/hashtag-search but i'm getting empty Data back as Json Result.

```
    {
  "data": [
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "UVZAGRFdEZAEdjRTlGYkROUk9XRk1PR1o0TnpsTGEwcEJVVE5mVTI1SmFuQkhXRzV0UldRM2JWaFdla0pKUkZAaUE1WcEZAOelZAZAYjFRMFptZAEhTbHB6ZADJOWWRWbHpTSFpUZAG1OZAlUyOVNjMVpHZAVdGclpUZA3RXZAz09"
    },
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/17843934877037015/recent_media?access_token=myAccessToken&pretty=0&user_id=myUserID&limit=25&after=UVZAGRFdEZAEdjRTlGYkROUk9XRk1PR1o0TnpsTGEwcEJVVE5mVTI1SmFuQkhXRzV0UldRM2JWaFdla0pKUkZAaUE1WcEZAOelZAZAYjFRMFptZAEhTbHB6ZADJOWWRWbHpTSFpUZAG1OZAlUyOVNjMVpHZAVdGclpUZA3RXZAz09"
  }
}
```

Thank you so much for any proposed help :)

Comment: Me too, last Friday was still worked, now even using fb developer tools also return empty.

Comment: Man - so happy to find this. Thought I had messed up and blocked my facebook app when I ran a test and hit the graph API from two different places concurrently ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an active bug causing this. A fix should be landing soon. Please subscribe to the bug report below for updates;
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/307613840758756/

https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/471343314132946/

Comment: The bug is fixed now: Hashtag Search works as expected again.

Comment: Thank you guys for clarifying the situation!